# Protobuf-net Serialize creating hex characters

Tags: c#, xml, serialization, xml-serialization, protobuf-net

I'm currently doing a POC to prove that Protobuf-net is faster than the native C# serializer. But I'm experiencing a bug? on the serialize response.

Here is the Error

nativeResult

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<userInformation xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <age>22</age>
  <education>Cavite State University</education>
  <name>Ronald Estacion</name>
  <address>
    <city>Cavite</city>
    <country>PH</country>
    <street>Torjak Street</street>
    <subd>Yari ka ngayon</subd>
  </address>
</userInformation>
```

protoresult

[image: Proto]

Here is my code.

```
var nativeSerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(UserInformation));
var nativeStream = new MemoryStream();
var protoStream = new MemoryStream();
nativeSerializer.Serialize(nativeStream, CreateDetaulUserInformation());
var nativeResult = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(nativeStream.ToArray());
Serializer.Serialize(protoStream, CreateDetaulUserInformation());
var protoResult = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(protoStream.ToArray());
```

Here is the UserInformation object.

```
//[ProtoContract]
[XmlType("address")]
public class Address
{
    //[ProtoMember(1)]
    [XmlElement("city", Order = 1)]
    public string City { get; set; }

    //[ProtoMember(2)]
    [XmlElement("country", Order = 2)]
    public string Country { get; set; }

    //[ProtoMember(3)]
    [XmlElement("street", Order = 3)]
    public string Street { get; set; }

    //[ProtoMember(4)]
    [XmlElement("subd", Order = 4)]
    public string Subdivision { get; set; }
}

//[ProtoContract]
[XmlType("userInformation")]
public class UserInformation
{
    //[ProtoMember(1)]
    [XmlElement("age", Order = 1)]
    public int Age { get; set; }

    //[ProtoMember(2)]
    [XmlElement("education", Order = 2)]
    public string Education { get; set; }

    //[ProtoMember(3)]
    [XmlElement("name", Order = 3)]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    //[ProtoMember(4)]
    [XmlElement("address", Order = 4)]
    public Address Address { get; set; }
}
```

NOTE: I've also tried using `ProtoContract` as the attribute but it has the same result. Protobuf-net supports `XmlType` aswell so i commented those attributes.

Comment: What is the encoding for your XML file?

Comment: What you call the "native C# serializer" is the NET XML Serializer.  The output is XML (text). ProtoBuf is a *binary* serializer.  You are comparing apples and tomatoes.  The unprintable leading chars are the serialized binary representation of 22 (age). Everything is working as it is supposed to. Compare the output of the NET BinaryFormatter to ProtoBuf for a more similar comparison.

Comment: @Plutonix how do i achieve an xml string output?

Comment: @DevEstacion base-64 can be transferred inside xml - note that doing so introduces unnecessary overheads, though

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's your error:

```
var protoResult = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(protoStream.ToArray());
```

protobuf is a **binary** protocol; it is **not** text, and is specifically not UTF8. What you are doing is attempting to **decode** a UTF-8 buffer into a string when the input data is not a UTF-8 buffer.

If you want to turn a raw `byte[]` into a `string`, then `Convert.ToBase64String` is your friend. But if you *can* avoid doing that: it is better to treat it as binary end-to-end if possible.

As a very minor thing: there's no need to call `ToArray()` here - that forces an extra array copy. If possible, use `GetBuffer()` **combined with** `.Length` (the underlying buffer is oversized); i.e.

```
string base64 = Convert.ToBase64String(
    protoStream.GetBuffer(), 0, (int)protoStream.Length);
```

Comment: The problem is that we have a legacy webservice, it accepts Xml request and Xml response, so I was finding a way to make a faster serialization/deserialization of the xmls

Comment: @DevEstacion protobuf-net is *not* an xml serializer; it talks "protobuf"

Comment: ♦ as i thought, i was just wondering if i could use it's speed in deserialization and serialization as xml. Thanks.